# Word for "someone whom the law is enforced upon"

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a word for someone whom the law is enforced upon, any ideas?

Example : Law needs to disregard the personal beliefs of the enforcers as well as the _____

Comment: .......Citizen?

Comment: Someone is sure to suggest "enforcee" or "law-enforcee".  The [OED](http://www.oed.com/noresults?browseType=sortAlpha&noresults=true&page=1&pageSize=20&q=enforcee&scope=ENTRY&sort=entry&type=dictionarysearch) says "No dictionary entries found for ‘enforcee’".  Let's keep it that way.

Comment: "perp" --------

Comment: Please edit your question after going over the "question checklist" for asking good [single word request](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) questions. You need to specify the context, and it would also be helpful to have information about any words you have already considered and discarded.

Comment: Consider "... as well as *those apprehended*".

Comment: @Lawrence - Isn't the law enforced upon everyone?

Comment: @HotLicks The law *applies* to everyone, but technically it's only *enforced* on those that the authorities interact with.

Comment: @Lawrence - And who does the law not interact with?  3-year-olds?

Comment: @HotLicks [Enforce](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/enforce) has the notion of the use of force to compel compliance. I'm distinguishing between that active notion and the passive notion of the law *applying* to everyone. Example: if a person drives faster than the speed limit and the cops don't pull them over, the driver is breaking the law but that law isn't being enforced.

Comment: Miscreants, for the most part.

Answer (score 1):

"Subject", maybe?

A police officer might write "I informed the subject that according to city ordinances, he needs to keep his hedge trimmed so it doesn't encroach on the sidewalk."

"Subject" doesn't have the criminal connotations of "suspect" or "defendant".

Answer (score 1):

**governed** : "the body of people who are citizens of a particular government" –[vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/governed)

> Law needs to disregard the personal beliefs of the enforcers as well as the *governed*.

*Civilians* works as well IMO (as would *citizenry*), as this context makes note of "the enforcers". Although police officers are both, technically, citizens *and* civilians, I don't think anyone would bat an eye at the distinction between *us* (the governed) and *The Man*.

See also (if you want to get derogatory), [**skell**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skell).

An apt idiom would be *general populace*, but it still needs context (e.g., "the enforcers") to denote what the distinction is that you're making from them.

Answer (score 0):

"Defendant" or "suspect." An indication of the nature of the law being enforced would probably elicit additional words.

Answer (score 0):

[Lawbreaker](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lawbreaker) is maybe the word you are looking for.

> noun: a person who violates the law